# Children's book about a talking alien baby (who lives on the moon?)

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I have been looking for this book for a long while. I remember being charmed by it when I was 8 - so 2000. In England, UK if it helps. The cover was a turquoise green colour. Some plot points I can recall:

- Either set on the moon, or heavily featured the moon
- Main character was a young woman named Tipperary (the song 'The Way to Tipperary' featured heavily in the story, her mother used to sing it as a lullaby)
- She had adopted a baby boy (at least, I don't think he was biologically hers) who was either an alien or an advanced human - he was very intelligent and could talk clearly, but still an infant
- His catchphrase was 'holy moly'  and this was also his nickname
- Tipperary had a bad relationship with her mother because of the baby
- Tipperary had an ex who was obnoxious and who showed up and kick-started the plot (can't remember details)
- Tipperary, the baby, and possibly a dog, lived in a campervan and travelled around a lot, possibly on the moon
- I am so sure the phrase 'holy moly' featured in the title but I'm not finding anything on Google...

Despite remembering weird little details, I can't find any info on this book! Please help if you can, I'd love to read it again, it had such a delightful tone and I'm sure there were more in the series.

Answer (score 5):

You're thinking of *[Spacebaby](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/000675175X)* by Henrietta Bradford! I read it in school when I was around 8.

[image]

Comment: :) If you add even something as simple as "He does use the phrase 'Holy Moly' and her name is Tipperary", it would add more to your answer. As it is, it looks like his guardian/friend is **Hector** Tipperary.

Comment: Yesss this is it! You honestly have no idea how happy I am! Thank you!

Comment: @Piper: If you click on the green checkmark to accept the answer, it will give Tez and you some points, and will mark it as answered in the system.